# New log file not generating?

Tags: java, logging, sunone

Today I made a backup of all log files of my Web Application on `SunOneWebServer`. I moved all the existing log files in new Folder Log_Bkp.  But now new log files are not being generated. In the code we have

```
(!createLogfile())
 throw exception
```

But no exception being thrown too. Not able to understand why is it happening? On my local `Apache Tomcat` server its working fine. If you need more information please comment.

Comment: Did you move the directory too? The general principle for logging is: files are created, folders are not.

Comment: What kind of logging system are you using? Have you tried debugging a log statement to see what happens? Is your directory structure still correct?

Comment: @crnlx-No i created a new directory inside the existing logs directory. In code log_file_location is the path of logs directory

Comment: Does it have the right permission?

Comment: @crnlx- Whose permission and what kind of permission? Before moving the logs to backup directory it was writing properly

Comment: @RobertH- We are creating a new filename.log if log file is not there otherwise apending to existing file. And the directory structure is still correct.

Comment: The permission of the new directory which you created. Ref: "i created a new directory inside the existing logs directory"

Comment: @crnlx- We don't need to write in new directory it should create in the existing directory only.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - I gathered that, but are you using java.util.logging, log4j, logback, a home brewed solution or some other library to do your logging? Can you show us some relevant code? Have you run your code in a debugger to find out what your program is expecting to have happen vs what you are expecting to have happen?

Comment: Have you tried [remote debugging](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html)?

Comment: @RobertH- I am using java.util.logging. And regarding code it is in my office system. So if possible will give you tomorrow.

Comment: Did you move the files when the server was still running? Log files are created once (when first needed) and then if you delete/move them they will not be recreated. You're better off using the built in support for RollingFileAppending instead of moving files while being used by your application.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg- Yes i moved them while the server was running :(After restarting the server the new files are being created.Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the files while the server was still running.
When i try this in Apache Tomcat local server it gives an error that it is being used by some system.
But on Server it did not gave any warning.
But when we restarted the server new files are being created.

> P.S: Whenever we move or delete any files on the server, please ensure
>   that the server is stopped first.